# I have lifted my sails.js app. I modified my local.js to configure https on port 8111. However I'm not able to get anything on Https://localhost:8111/

Tags: node.js, https, configuration, sails.js

This is my modified `local.js`

```
ssl: {
  key: require('fs').readFileSync('/Users/bpoludas/Documents/NodeProjects/gita/config/ssl/key.pem'),
  cert: require('fs').readFileSync('/Users/bpoludas/Documents/NodeProjects/gita/config/ssl/cert.pem')
},
port: process.env.PORT || 8111,
environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
```

When I lift the sails app it lifts fine. However from the browser it doesnt load. Can anyone help?

Comment: does the console indicate on lift that it is using port 8111?

Comment: Check your environment configuration. Can be, that there is port explicitly set in environment. And provide here what you got in console after start the server.

Comment: The console does indicate the the app is now available on 8111. I'm on Macbook pro. I checked the ports and the port 8111 does show as up and listening whenever I lift sails